# Create Entity Framework model based on an existing database in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, scaffolding

I'm trying to create an Entity Framework model based on an existing database in ASP.NET Core. I can't make Scaffold-DbContext to work though! I have searched Stackoverflow and other websites to see if the packages in my ASP.NET Core Web Application project are not correct but I still can't make it work. I get the following error when running the Scaffold-DbContext in Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.;Database=TravelAgency;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
System.AggregateException: Ett eller flera fel har uppstï¿½tt. ---> System.MethodAccessException: Ett fï¿½rsï¿½k av metoden Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Configuration.Internal.ModelConfiguration.get_EntityConfigurations() 
att komma ï¿½t metoden Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityTypeNameComparer..ctor() misslyckades.    vid Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Configuration.Internal.ModelConfiguration.get_EntityConfigurations()
```

Sorry, I didn't find the way to display the errors in Package Manager Console in English. It's about System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
My project.json-file looks like this:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
"EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "type": "build",
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "type": "build",
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
"NuGet.CommandLine": "3.5.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {

"net461": {}

  },

  "publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
}
  },
  "scripts": {
"prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
"BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
  },
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-TravelAgencyApplication-3fa3cffa-93a0-470d-b08a-145e604eb5f7"
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Best Regards, Attila

Answer (score 0):

You should try running the following command.

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

[Here is the official documentation on reverse engineering a db into your models. Make sure you have the correct packages installed per this link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/existing-db)

Comment: Thanks destructi6n, but do you mean that I should create a Local Database in order for this to work? I have earlier created a Sql Server 2012 database and I can't seem to make Scaffold-DbContext to work, even though I use the command you mentioned.

Comment: What you should do is replace my connection string (i.e. Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;) with one pointed to your database. I've used this command before with my localdb instance. This command should work for you if you provide it your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of issues with making this work with .net core from the package manager console. I ended issuing the command from the command line, which I had more success with. See here on how to do this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.

as an example, run the following from your project directory:

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=YourServer;Database=YourDb;Integrated Security=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --output-dir Models`

An issue was listed here, its now close but I still seemed to have issues: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5376

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I don't know exactly what I did, but I finally succeeded with Scaffold-DbContext command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=DATOR;Database=TravelAgency;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

which is a command that destructi6n described, adjusted to my SQL Server 2012 database. Now my project.json-file looks like this:

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
"emitEntryPoint": true,
"preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
"EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
  "type": "build",
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGenerators.Mvc": {
  "type": "build",
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
},
"NuGet.CommandLine": "3.5.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {

"net461": {}

  },

  "publishOptions": {
"include": [
  "wwwroot",
  "**/*.cshtml",
  "appsettings.json",
  "web.config"
]
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
"configProperties": {
  "System.GC.Server": true
}
  },
  "scripts": {
"prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
"postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
  "tools": {
"BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.SecretManager.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
  "imports": [
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
  },
  "userSecretsId": "aspnet-TravelAgencyApplication-3fa3cffa-93a0-470d-b08a-145e604eb5f7"
}
```

Kind Regards, Attila